Using Firebase in React Native Expo to trigger an iOS install Google Ads Conversion?
I am looking for a way to get Firebase working in an app built in React Native Expo, so that it gives out some sort of data for Google Ads to use and count as a conversion metric, when someone installs our iOS app by way of clicking on a Google Ad served to them.
It's shocking that Google hasn't made this easier, but there is currently no way of measuring Google Ads Conversions for an App Install campaign, without using Firebase.
I have been working with Google Ads support over the past month, and they have been unable to help me. So according to Google Ads support, the only way to count conversion metrics for iOS installs is to use Firebase embedded in our app to get some data out of the app once it's installed by an end user. Or some other 3rd party tool that they are unable to recommend or support.
Looking at embedding Firebase into how our app is currently architected in React Native Expo seems like a huge overhaul. Any tips or tricks? Has anyone made this work properly with Google Ads iOS app installs campaigns?
